# bootstrap glyphicon isn't showing on buttons

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap. And I want to add some buttons.

I searched online for bootstrap buttons with icons and here is an example of what I used:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn-sm" name="delete_row" onClick="return confirm('Are You Sure ?!!')">
      Delete
    </button>
```

The result was a red delete button with no icon in it.

I searched for it and they said, that I should use glyphicon, so I added this line of code to the button:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span>
```

[image]

This small square should be a like a trash can or something, but it is not showing properly.

I tried this too, but still the same result:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>Delete
```

Here is the library I use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/font.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup your fonts folder on the same level as your css folder, where bootstrap is located, and put the glyphicon fonts there. Then find the following lines in your bootstrap css file and make sure they also point to the font folder.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';

  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
  url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), 
  url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), 
  url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See example: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2xakuyem/)

HTML

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
 Delete<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: no, I've already tried it, and post it in my question, no result

Comment: maybe i should different version of bootstrap ?

Comment: Please check bootstrap css path properly.

Comment: it works, because, my web app is responsive, so the path is working